# Running an Executable Jar using Maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jenkins, executable-jar

Is it possible to run an executable jar file using Maven?

A brief introduction to setup:

- Environment is running on Centos
- I have included the exec plugin into my maven POM and have it running a shell script that is meant to run the jar file and works fine using the terminal but I get Unable to access jarfile error when run in maven.
- I have chmod the jar, shell and other files to 777
- I have editted the sudoers file as suggested by other posts
- I have also given maven and Jenkins root access

All of these changes still result in the above error and I have run out of ideas.

HELP!!!

POM File

```
 <pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
<url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<executions>
<execution>
<!--  Run our Password Checker script  -->
<id>Password Checker</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>exec</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<executable>src/pass/passCheck.sh</executable>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>eviware</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.5.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>verify</phase>
<goals>
<goal>test</goal>
</goals>
<id>MPesa-Tests</id>
<configuration>
<projectFile>src/test/GenericAPI-G2-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
<outputFolder>SoapUI-Results/</outputFolder>
<junitReport>true</junitReport>
<exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
<printReport>false</printReport>
<projectProperties>
<value>message=Tests Completed</value>
</projectProperties>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>/usr/share/Surefire/</outputDirectory>
<reportDirectories>
<reportDirectories>/usr/share/Surefire/reports/</reportDirectories>
</reportDirectories>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Unable to access jarfile xxxxx.jar

Comment: Is your script using the absolute or an relative path to the JAR? Since maven and the script does not execute in the same folder as the script, this might trip you up...

Comment: so the script is currently executing in a relative path, should I change it to the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same need to execute a Spring Boot packaged application and solved it by using the maven dependency plugin to copy the artifact to /tmp (or anywhere for that matter) and then using the maven exec plugin to execute that jar using the exec:exec goal.